# How to find index of array of object given a property value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object that holds two objects. Each object has a couple properties; one being `dealerNo`. Given the value of `dealerNo`, how would I get the index of that object?

Comment: Always include the code that you are asking about.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex):

```js
const getIndexByDealerNo = (arr=[], dealerNo) =>
  arr.findIndex(e => e.dealerNo===dealerNo);
  
const arr = [ { dealerNo:1 }, { dealerNo: 2 } ];

console.log( getIndexByDealerNo(arr, 1) );
console.log( getIndexByDealerNo(arr, 2) );
console.log( getIndexByDealerNo(arr, 11) );
```

Comment: We tend not to answer poor questions that don't belong here in the first place as it just encourages more poor questions.